# how to change Google reCaptcha's "I'm not a robot" language to English

Tags: javascript, html

I have been looking for ways to change the language `"google reCaptcha"` on several sites and I found a way on this site.

But dear, I don't understand the code problem,
my position is in Indonesia, my site's language is english, but the language `"google reCaptcha"` is using is Indonesian.

Can someone help me change the language `"google reCaptcha"` to English.
Can someone write code for me to use, along with where I paste the code given,
what is the function.php theme, header or other position, via cpanel/file manager.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I understand that English is not your first language, but your question is vague and difficult to understand. Also, StackOverflow is not a code writing service and asking for copy/paste solutions is against the site guidelines

Answer (score 0):

As default, the language was be selected by browser language but  you can choose the language via the api.js file,
for example:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?explicit&hl=YOUR_LANG_CODE">
```

Replace YOUR_LANG_CODE with your selected language like `ar`, `en`, `it`, etc.

Comment: can I add the code in themes function.php @midoelhawy

Comment: in your front end side you need only to add parameter hl to your api js src..... if you use recaptcha V2, you have already called script like this `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit `
change this to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit&hl=YOU_LANG_CODE`

Comment: I add code in my active theme header

and works in the language I choose.

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?explicit&hl=en">`

because I don't understand the code problem, can there be another problem, if I set the code in my theme header

thank you